# Is there a way to request a remote file without file size in the reply?

Tags: http, curl, http-headers, wget

We can get the size of a file using curl. But is there a way to get a response that wont have a "Content-Length" attribute?

```
theuser@thecomp ~/dl
╰─➤  curl -sI www.google.com

Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8Hg3VYH5KpGFoAPd9IGACw
Content-Length: 261
```

Comment: `-I` stands for "fetch just the HTTP header", so you probably have to do some post-processing to just get the fields that you want.

Comment: Specifying the size when it is known helps both the client and the server.  However, there are situations when the size cannot be known in advance, so it is perfectly permissible for the server to not specify it. The error message you get from http://whatismyipaddress.com/ if you visit it with `curl` does not have the `Content-Length:` header, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, HTTP has several ways to respond that don't provide you with the size up front. Either it...

1. sends the response and closes the connection when it is done (HTTP 1.0 style), or
2. sends a [chunked-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) response.